# Nested data in JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am having issues trying to get hold of nested data in my JSON file.

Can anyone help me please? i am trying to create a megamenu.

```
$.getJSON("js/nav.json", function (data)  {
    $.each(data.navigation, function (i, navigation)  {
        var jsondata = "<li class='top-level'><a href='/" + this.link + "'>" + this.title + "</a></li>";
        $.each(this.headingArray, function ()  {
            alert(hello);
        });
        $(jsondata).appendTo("ul.nav");
    });
  });
});
```

And here is the sample JSON file im reading from

```
{
    "navigation": [
            {
                    "title": "Home",
                    "link": ""
 },
            {
                    "title": "Find your ski holiday",
                    "link": "#URLhere",
                    "headingArray": [
                            {
                                    "heading": [
                                            {
                                                    "title": "Destinations",
                                                    "link": "#URLhere",
                                                    "subheading": [
                                                            {
                                                                    "title": "Andorra",
                                                                    "link": "#URLhere"
},
                                                            {
                                                                    "title": "Austria",
                                                                    "link": "#URLhere"
},
```

Any help would be much appreciated please?

demo - http://dev.thirstythursdays.co.uk/menu-json3

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about *what your question is*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your objects have different properties, like `headingArray`, `subheading` etc, before you try to iterate through `this.headingArray` you have to check if it's defined or not.

So add something like

```
if (this.headingArray){
    //iterate through this.headingArray
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Xy4/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is how your response is being parsed.

Notice that, because of the way your JSON is structured, not every resulting element in your array contains a `headingArray`/`subheading` field.

[image]

For example, if you look at the first element in the JSON response array, you can clearly see that the object does not contain a `headingArray` field:

```
{
    "navigation": [
    {
        "title": "Home",
        "link": "" // No headingArray in here...
    }, {
        "title": "Find your ski holiday",
        "link": "#URLhere",
        "headingArray": [
        {
```

What you should do is:

- either restructure your json to only contain homogeneous elements,
- or rewrite your parsing logic to check for inexistent fields before
  trying to access their values.